# Nancy: Use NTLM if available, if not, carry on anonymously

Tags: .net, webserver, windows-authentication, ntlm, nancy

I have a Nancy server which is successfully issuing an NTLM challenge and resolving the user.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9000"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}

internal class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
        listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

However, what I'd really like is for NTLM to be used if it available. I would like to continue processing even if the NTLM authentication step fails in order to support processing in a manner similar to the following:

```
    public StatusModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            var requestEnvironment = (IDictionary<string, object>) Context.Items["OWIN_REQUEST_ENVIRONMENT"];
            var user = (IPrincipal) requestEnvironment["server.User"];

            var userDetails = user == null
                ? null
                : new
                {
                    Username = user.Identity.Name,
                    IsAuthenticated = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                    AuthenticationType = user.Identity.AuthenticationType
                };

            return Response.AsJson(new {TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("O"), Status = "OK", UserDetails = userDetails});
        };
    }
```

How can I allow the user to fail NTLM but still process the request?

Comment: The request will still be processed; there just won't be any authenticated identity associated with it.

Comment: @DavidW  The problem is that if NTML is enabled then it will issue the 401 handshake, if anonymous is enabled then it'll just accept anyone and never issue the handshake.

Comment: Could you not set up conditional authentication via the AuthenticationSchemeSelectorDelegate?

Comment: @DavidW I thought of that, but I'd have to maintain state via a cookie so I'd know if I had already tried and failed the handshake.  It's a possibility, just wondering if there's some client side magic I could do that would be more effective\pleasant.